# jQuery / Ajax: how to refer to dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, dynamically-generated

I am using the below Ajax call in order to fill a placeholder container ("`containerSub`") with some HTML elements, e.g. containing standard textareas like the following:

```
<textarea rows="1" class="form-control elastic">Some text</textarea>
```

Now I would like to refer to all the elements with class "`elastic`" in the success function of the Ajax call (like in the example below) but this doesn't work as I guess the elements gets added to the DOM dynamically.

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this without reloading the page ?

```
$('#categories').on('change', function() {
    var category = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php?node=fetchQuestions',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            category: category
        },
        error:function(err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        },
        success:function(html) {
            $('#containerSub').html(html);
            $('.elastic').elastic();
        }
    });
});
```

**Container before Ajax call:**

```
<div id="containerSub"></div>
```

**Container afterwards (example):**

```
<div id="containerSub">
    <textarea rows="1" class="form-control elastic">Some text</textarea>
</div>
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a deferred callback so that *after* the HTML has been injected, you apply your .elastic() as such:

```
success:function(html) {
    $('#containerSub').html(html).promise().done(function(){
        $(this).find('.elastic').elastic();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - never seen that before. :)

Comment: Deferreds and the whole jQ Promise framework are powerful and highly useful as your sites/applications become more interactive. Learning how to use them effectively is definitely a skill worth developing; this should help get you started: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: you should mark this as the answer if you are using it

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php?node=fetchQuestions',
    cache: false,
    data: {
        category: category
    },
    error:function(err) {
        alert(err.statusText);
    },
    success:function(html) {
        $('#containerSub').html(html).promise().done(function() {
             $('.elastic').elastic();
        });
    }
});
```

This is probably what you're looking for.